# How to stop fire from going out without netherrack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to set a hopper on fire on Minecraft, but I don't know how to keep it burning. Any ideas? (I'm not good with commands)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this command:

```
/gamerule doFireTick false
```

This will disable all fire from going out, and will also disable fire spreading, but if the fire on the hopper is the only fire, then this is the way.

To turn fire tick back on, do the same command but change false to true.

Comment: To expand, the `doFireTick` gamerule tells whether or not Minecraft should "touch" fire in any way. This means it cannot spread, and it cannot be put out. A `FireTick` in Minecraft going around the world checking if certain conditions are met, and if they are, then spreading or putting out a fire.

Comment: While this works, it disables fire for the whole world, so keep that in mind when using it.

Answer (score 5):

Update to 1.13: the syntax and functioning of commands has changed (twice). It is now possible to combine all into one <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Always active</kbd> command block:

```
execute unless block X Y Z fire run setblock X Y Z fire
```

where `X`, `Y` and `Z` are the X, Y and Z coordinates of the fire block, respectively

Breakup:

```
execute unless                  # unless (if ... is not)              
    block                       # the block at 
    X Y Z                       # the coordinates [X,Y,Z]            
    fire                        # is fire
    run setblock                # place a block
        X Y Z                   # at the coordinates [X,Y,Z]  
        fire                    # of fire
```

Resets the fire within 1/20th of a second after burnout, and is lag-friendly*. The command block can be anywhere. Here is a screenshot:

[image: simple]

<sub>* as lag friendly as 1.13 can be</sub>

Comment: ... all of this redstone (except the clock, but that's inferior to a repeating command block) is unneeded, you can just run `/setblock X Y Z minecraft:fire`, which will do nothing if there is already fire there.

Comment: @ppperry but this is more lag-friendly imo